# Python Pandas for loop over folder concat numpy array to each xlsx file in folder

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This is my first post so please forgive me if I don't follow normal procedures

one - I am trying to concat a numpy array to each xlsx file in folder
two - the correct numpy array should be concatenated based on the number of rows in each xlsx file. for example *.xlsx has 3 rows then 7X3 numpy should be concatenated axis = 1
I have employed if elif statments (not sure if this is the best way)
any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

and it refers back to:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-4c4e68cdca04> in <module>
     22         final.to_excel(f)
     23     elif len(dfs)== 2:
---> 24         df1 = pd.read_excel(dfs, skiprows= range(0,0), usecols= ('R'))
     25         result = df1.transpose()
     26         noiV = np.array([result])
```

the following is the code that I am using:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = ('/home/keven/sept2020aka/testing1/md/')
dfs = pd.DataFrame()

#fileswb =  os.listdir(path)
fileswb = glob.glob('/home/keven/sept2020aka/testing1/md/*.xlsx')
for f in fileswb:
    dfs = pd.read_excel(f)
    if len(dfs)== 0:
        print("there are no properties")
    elif len(dfs)== 1:
        df1 = pd.read_excel(dfs, skiprows= range(0,0), usecols= ('R'))
        result = df1.transpose()
        noiV = np.array([result])
        onesV = np.ones((7,1))
        NOIV = (noiV*onesV).astype(int)
        np.random.seed(123)
        R0 = sp.random.uniform(1.000,1.045, size=(7,1))
        noi = (NOIV*R0).astype(int)
        noia = noi.reshape(7,1)
        noib = pd.DataFrame(data=noia)
        final = pd.concat([dfs,noib], axis=1)
        final.to_excel(f)
    elif len(dfs)== 2:
        df1 = pd.read_excel(dfs, skiprows= range(0,0), usecols= ('R'))
        result = df1.transpose()
        noiV = np.array([result])
        onesV = np.ones((7,2))
        NOIV = (noiV*onesV).astype(int)
        np.random.seed(123)
        R0 = sp.random.uniform(1.000,1.045, size=(7,2))
        noi = (NOIV*R0).astype(int)
        noia = noi.reshape(7,2)
        noib = pd.DataFrame(data=noia)
        final = pd.concat([dfs,noib], axis=1)
        final.to_excel(f)
    elif len(dfs)== 3:
        df1 = pd.read_excel(dfs, skiprows= range(0,0), usecols= ('R'))
        result = df1.transpose()
        noiV = np.array([result])
        onesV = np.ones((7,3))
        NOIV = (noiV*onesV).astype(int)
        np.random.seed(123)
        R0 = sp.random.uniform(1.000,1.045, size=(7,3))
        noi = (NOIV*R0).astype(int)
        noia = noi.reshape(7,3)
        noib = pd.DataFrame(data=noia)
        final = pd.concat([dfs,noib], axis=1)
        final.to_excel(f)
    
    elif len(dfs)== 4:
        df1 = pd.read_excel(dfs, skiprows= range(0,0), usecols= ('R'))
        result = df1.transpose()
        noiV = np.array([result])
        onesV = np.ones((7,4))
        NOIV = (noiV*onesV).astype(int)
        np.random.seed(123)
        R0 = sp.random.uniform(1.000,1.045, size=(7,4))
        noi = (NOIV*R0).astype(int)
        noia = noi.reshape(7,4)
        noib = pd.DataFrame(data=noia)
        final = pd.concat([dfs,noib], axis=1)
        final.to_excel(f)
    
    elif len(dfs)== 5:
        df1 = pd.read_excel(dfs, skiprows= range(0,0), usecols= ('R'))
        result = df1.transpose()
        noiV = np.array([result])
        onesV = np.ones((7,5))
        NOIV = (noiV*onesV).astype(int)
        np.random.seed(123)
        R0 = sp.random.uniform(1.000,1.045, size=(7,5))
        noi = (NOIV*R0).astype(int)
        noia = noi.reshape(7,5)
        noib = pd.DataFrame(data=noia)
        final = pd.concat([dfs,noib], axis=1)
        final.to_excel(f)
    
    else:
        print("there are too many properties")
```

Comment: I am not familiar with `pd.read_excel`, but it seems strange that you're passing the result of one read_excel call into another. Should it be `df1 = pd.read_excel(f, skiprows= range(0,0), usecols= ('R'))` instead? (I replaced `dfs` with `f`, the file path)

Comment: change all of these lines of code: `df1 = pd.read_excel(dfs, skiprows= range(0,0), usecols= ('R'))` to `df1 = dfs.copy()`. Also delete: `dfs = pd.DataFrame()`

Comment: Edit your question and use `\`` brackets for code expressions to clarify the question. Try double space after the broken line to start it from a new line, because the question is a mess.

Comment: Please, remove salutations. [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)